# H1 tag pushes div down

Tags: html

Hello I have a problem and I cant find a good explained answer on the web.

I have two div's when I type some text with a h1 tag in the second div it pushes the div down. Even when I make the margin-top greater.

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link href="css/normalize" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style>

      #one {
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: red
      }

      #two {
        width: 100%;
        height: 150px;
        background-color: blue
      }

      h1 {
        margin: 50px 0;
      }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="one">

    </div>
    <div id="two">
      <h1>Hoi</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Example Picture
[image: Example Picture]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The adjoining margins of two or more (or parent and child) box can combine to form a single margin, this combination is called collapsed margin.

W3C Reference: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins

Any value of overflow different from its default (visible) applied to the parent will prevent collapse.

Use `overflow: hidden` in the div #two will solve it.